# Convert jQuery Mobile slider to jQuery UI slider and change content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changecontent()
    {
    if (document.getElementById("slider").value<33)
        {
        $("#1").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#2").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#3").fadeOut("slow");
    } else if (document.getElementById("slider").value>33 && document.getElementById("slider").value<66)
        {
        $("#1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#2").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#3").fadeOut("slow");
    } else if (document.getElementById("slider").value>66)
        {
        $("#1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#2").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#3").fadeIn("slow");
        };
    };
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hide {display:none;}
    .show {display:inherit;}
</style>

<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
<div id="content">
    <div id="1" class="show" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;">A</div>
    <div id="2" class="hide" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;">B</div>
    <div id="3" class="hide" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;">C</div>
</div>
```

As the code above stands, this will create an HTML5 range slider that fades between 3 different div's depending on the position of the slider's knob. My problem is that the slider looks horrible in IE. I need to customize it's appearance to look uniform across browsers.

I've tried using jQuery Mobile, which resolves this issue. However it causes a conflict with the js used in WordPress's twentytwelve theme. I've tried resolving those conflicts to no avail. I've loaded in jQuery UI and no conflicts occur.

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

The above code creates the UI slider, but I've been reading the jQuery API documentation and am not understanding how to alter my script to get the displayed content to change. Your expertise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MpT7Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="1" class="show" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;">A</div>
    <div id="2" class="hide" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;">B</div>
    <div id="3" class="hide" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;">C</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value < 33) {
                $("#1").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#2").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#3").fadeOut("slow");
            }
            else if (ui.value < 66) {
                $("#1").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#2").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#3").fadeOut("slow");
            }
            else {
                $("#1").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#2").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#3").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:inherit;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NxGZa/

Comment: Mayabelle, you are my hero!